# Excel Count specific number in column by today

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column A with values ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ) and column B with dates .

I need to have an output of how many values ( 8 ) I had yesterday by date in column A.

My formula for now is =COUNTIFS($A$2:$P$5000,"=" & TODAY(),$B$2:$B$5000,"=" & "8")

But something is not working and I can't get it to work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Countif Range should be column Range only not entire table.

If you are using Today(), your extract will not have today's date, you will need to look at Today()-1.
Try this:
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$**A**$5000,TODAY()-1,$B$2:$B$5000,8)

Comment: Thanks that worked.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$5000,TODAY()-1,$A$2:$A$5000,8)` instead? Judging by the description in the question column B holds the date and column A values 1 up to 9.

Comment: Yes I saw this and rewrote the formula in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since the Dates are in Column B. Condition criteria should be reversed.
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$5000,TODAY()-1,$A$2:$A$5000,8)